# EMI and reliability considerations for low-frequency, low-voltage DC load drive

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, emc, emi-filtering, low-side

In my application I need to drive a 240W pure-resistive load with a nominal voltage of 24V.
The input is a standard 280W AC-DC external power adapter, the Meanwell GST280A24.
The load switch is implemented with a low-side topology with a single power mosfet, driven by a MCU with a square PWM signal, 5V logic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXeIif.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to consistently and reliably drive my load with good efficiency, and I also need to keep EMI at a low level to be able to pass the EN 55011 conducted and radiated emissions test.
I therefore selected a very slow PWM frequency, 30 Hz.
I also decided to go hard on the gate resistor of the mosfet, since I want to avoid any turn-on spike and ringing problems. I also added an RC snubber.
The output signal on node MEAS, as seen at the oscilloscope, looks like a clean square wave, with a noticeable slope due to the input capacitance of the mosfet in series with the 10 kOhm resistor.
My question is: do I need any input filter, to protect the power adapter from voltage and current bursts and to filter out conducted and radiated emissions? Or is the frequency so low (30 Hz) that an input filter won't be needed? Do I need anyway to use an inductor coil in series with the 24V line to prevent a high inrush current to damage the power adapter when the circuit is switched on? What about the load? It is not ground referenced, and this raises many doubts regarding EMI behaviour. Do I need to go for a high-side topology instead? Or will It be fine to pass the EMC tests?

Comment: Is it 30 Hz or 30 kHz?

Comment: Typo corrected. 30 Hz

Comment: Depends. With good layout and decoupling it should be no problem. How does it look?

Comment: Regarding PCB layout, we try to keep the power paths as short as possible, avoiding rings patterns and antenna-like features. We have a solid ground plane to sink all the current. This ground plane is connected to the GND of the power adapter. The wires to the load are short and twisted. What about decoupling? Would you put a bunch of capacitors between +24V line and GND? If yes which size would you go for?

Comment: So you have measured the waveforms. Mind sharing the screenshots (preferably on either side of the load)? Or at least the rise & fall times of voltage and current.

Answer (score 0):

The power supply should be fine with the switched load. If you are worried beef it up with some extra capacitance close to the load.

As far as EMI goes: Let's think about parasitic inductances (in series wit the load) first. They will be unhappy when the transistor turns off the current flow. As I said, they are in series with the resistive load, forming an LR circuit. Estimate an upper bound for L, and compute the time constant L/R. If it is smaller than the fastest rise/fall time in your waveform, then all the voltage will drop across the resistor, and the inductance is simply not a problem.

Same train of thoughts apply to parasitic capacitances (across the load), on turn-on.

But in the end, nothing can beat actually testing the device on the bench.

BTW, do not simply add inductance between the source and the load. This will worsen the behaviour on turn-off. If you do, also place bypass capacitors close to the load.